# Print the pattern when I give input "CODER"

Tags: java, reverse

I have to print the following pattern in Java. The input is "CODER" and I have to print reverse triangle pattern and the output should be.

```
R
RE
RED
REDO
REDOC
```

My code is this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
public class pyramid {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  try {
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   String string;
   int length;
   System.out.print("Enter the String : ");
   string = scanner.nextLine();
   length = string.length();
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
     System.out.printf("%c ", string.charAt(j));
    }
    System.out.printf("%c\n", string.charAt(i));
   }

  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.err.println(e);
  }
 }
}
```

It is not working as it prints,

```
C
CO
COD
CODE
CODER
```

Please help, I am able to print directly the string but I have to print it in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print in reverse order, you must loop in reverse order too.
change your for loop initialization. set i=string.length()-1, same for j and i,j>=0, where I,j will decrement in each iteration (i--, j--). In "CODER", chartAt(0) is C and charAt(string.lenth()-1) is D.
So in short, loop in reverse order.

Comment: Alternatively, you could loop in forward order but access `string.charAt(string.length()-1-j)`